# Scrape page with generator

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, generator

I scraping a site with Beautiful Soup. The problem I have is that certain parts of the site are paginated with JS, with an unknown (varying) number of pages to scrape.
I'm trying to get around this with a generator, but it's my first time writing one and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it and figuring out if what I'm doing makes sense.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib2
import jabba_webkit as jw
import csv
import string
import re
import time

tlds = csv.reader(open("top_level_domains.csv", 'r'), delimiter=';')
sites = csv.writer(open("websites_to_scrape.csv", "w"), delimiter=',')

tld = "uz"
has_next = True
page = 0

def create_link(tld, page):
    if page == 0:
        link = "https://domaintyper.com/top-websites/most-popular-websites-with-" + tld + "-domain"
    else:
        link = "https://domaintyper.com/top-websites/most-popular-websites-with-" + tld + "-domain/page/" + repr(page)

    return link

def check_for_next(soup):
    disabled_nav = soup.find(class_="pagingDivDisabled")

    if disabled_nav:
        if "Next" in disabled_nav:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return True


def make_soup(link):
    html = jw.get_page(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    return soup

def all_the_pages(counter):
    while True: 
        link = create_link(tld, counter)
        soup = make_soup(link)
        if check_for_next(soup) == True:
            yield counter
        else:
            break
        counter += 1

def scrape_page(soup):
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'rankTable'})
    th = table.find('tbody')
    test = th.find_all("td")

    correct_cells = range(1,len(test),3)
    for cell in correct_cells:
        #print test[cell]
        url = repr(test[cell])
        content = re.sub("<[^>]*>", "", url)
        sites.writerow([tld]+[content])


def main():

    for page in all_the_pages(0):

        print page
        link = create_link(tld, page)
        print link
        soup = make_soup(link)
        scrape_page(soup)






main()
```

My thinking behind the code:
The scraper should get the page, determine if there is another page that follows, scrape the current page and move to the next one, repreating the process. If there is no next page, it should stop. Does that make sense how I'm going it here?

Comment: you could use selenium to load the JS content, find navigable buttons and still parse the HTML content with BS4.

Comment: the parsing works, the JS is not the problem.
the problem is that I have no idea how often to "klick next".
I'm trying to do that by checking if there still is a "next"-button everytime I scrape a page. If there is, I want to scrape that next page, if not, I want to break.

Comment: share a url where I can see that the HTML looks like.

Comment: https://domaintyper.com/top-websites/most-popular-websites-with-uz-domain

Answer (score 0):

As I told you, you could use selenium for programmatically clicking on the `Next` button, but since that is not an option for you, I can think of the following method to get the number of pages using pure BS4:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def page_count():
    pages = 1    
    url = "https://domaintyper.com/top-websites/most-popular-websites-with-uz-domain/page/{}"

    while True:
        html = requests.get(url.format(pages)).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

        table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'rankTable'})
        if len(table.find_all('tr')) <= 1:
            return pages
        pages += 1
```